# Access variable in defined in a function outside of that function

Tags: php, wordpress, scope, shortcode

Firstly: I know this has been asked before, but I've looked through a lot of questions/answers and I can't work out how to get any of them working. So, sorry about that.

So basically I'm writing some functions/shortcodes in Wordpress that mean that I can use a shortcode to publish Vine videos to a Wordpress blog:

```
function embedVine($atts) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "id" => ''
    ), $atts));

    $vine_id = $id;

   // I'm then doing a whole load of stuff involving $vine_id, including using it as a parameter to pass to different functions I've written that are separate to this function.
  // I should also mention that $vine_id is the id on the end of a Vine URL.
} add_shortcode("vine", "embedVine");
```

A user can then use the `[vine id="..."]` shortcode in the Wordpress editor.

I then have a function I've written but I don't want to execute it inside of the function above, otherwise it will run every time the function/shortcode runs which wouldn't be good. I instead need to execute it outside of the function but still use `$vine_id` as a parameter for it. However, as `$vine_id` was defined inside the function above, I cannot access it outside of the function.

Here is the second function:

```
function vineThumb($id) {
    $vine = file_get_contents("http://vine.co/v/{$id}");
    return $vine;
    // of course, it's a lot more complicated than this but for the sake of this, it works.
} vineThumb($vine_id);
```

Executing the function would return http://vine.co/v/{$vine_id}. How would I make the $vine_id function accessible outside of the shortcode function (the first one)?

Hope I've explained that clearly enough, I'm not a PHP programmer as you can probably tell but I know enough to get by. This sort has me stumped though. Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if those two functions are located in the same file but try this. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
$vine_id = null; //Define it outside the function

function embedVine($atts) {

    global $vine_id; //Refers to $vine_id outside the function

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "id" => ''
    ), $atts));

    $vine_id = $id; //$vine_id now has the value of $id when embedVine exits
} add_shortcode("vine", "embedVine");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work :( thanks for your help though :) I think what I need to do is be able to somehow return $vine_id as a result of a function which is accessible to my secondary function. Not sure how to do that though :/